# declare function of class inline

Tags: c++, class, inline, virtual-functions

i want to implement i function member of a class in my main() to use functions from there.

I have this class:

```
class CMD{

        public:
            CMD();
            ~CMD();
            virtual void execute();
    };
```

I want to implement the execute() function in my main() to pass the resulting class to a function.

I tried this:

```
main(){

//....

class : public CMD {
    public:
    void execute(){
      next(); //This function is declared in the scope of main()
    } 
  } cmd1;

otherFunction(&cmd1);
}
```

The otherFunction() function  would then do something like this:

```
void otherFunction(CMD* cmd){
   cmd->execute();
}
```

What ever i try it fails. I'm coming from C# and Java and i can do such stuff there. Is that even possible in C++?

During compining i get the following error:

> undefined reference to `vtable for CMD'

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. You should try to create a minimal C++ program and post it here to explain what you are trying to do

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Local classes are a thing. And there's nothing bogus about an unnamed class that inherits something.

Comment: @JesperJuhl - Why not? I clearly see them wanting to pass an object that adheres to an interface. If the object is a one-time local thing, and the interface is simple, then creating a simple local class (and not bothering to name it since we immediately declare an object) seems pretty sensible.

Comment: @Manuel - *"What ever i try it fails"* is not a useful problem statement. Do you get an error? A crash? Nasal demons flying out your nose? It's important to your problem. Post a [mcve] please.

Comment: @StoryTeller - I updated my description to answer you question

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't know why you prefer local class. In my experience, local class is not well-supported in compilers. It's not unusual to encounter some bizarre bug and even crash.

Comment: @liliscent - Don't extrapolate and straw-man what I said please. I never claimed to prefer anything. I said a thing can have its place, depending on circumstances.

Comment: @ManuelSchmitt - I figured that's your problem. Wanted you to confirm the error I suspected. Refer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @StoryTeller - What do you mean with "Refer to the duplicate question"?

Comment: I just closed your post as a duplicate of another. There's a link at the top...